# Use Angular with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm taking tutorial in [CodeSchool](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/1/section/1/video/1) about angular and I try to create my own experiment in `html5` and `angular` new version in `vs2012`.

I try to test angular repeat but the problem is `HTML5` can't render my angular.

When I try to run my page, the repeater only show the angular statement `{{item.name}}:{{item.quantity}}` not the result. Why? *-"show code below"*

**Angular script** :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**application.js** :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/application.js"></script>
```

```js
$(function () {
    var app = angular.module('zaskarCorp', []);
    app.controller('kirito', function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [{
            "name": "dual sword",
            "quantity": 2
        }, {
            "name": "gun",
            "quantity": 1
        }, {
            "name": "laser sword",
            "quantity": 1
        }];
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="zaskarCorp">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/application.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="kirito">
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in items">
      <span>{{item.name}}:{{item.quantity}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see I add `data-` in my angular because I use `html5`. *-"I hate warnings"*

Comment: You've answered your own question. You've added data- to the angular directive thus no longer making it an angular directive. Ask yourself, how do you expect that angular knows what data-ng-controller means? It doesn't, and since the directive is not now being processed your angular expressions are not being evaluated.

Comment: Are you receiving an error? You have `var app = agular.module...`, do you mean `var app = angular.module...`? You also have `$(funtion()...`, do you mean `(function()...`?

Comment: @rism, angular [normalizes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#matching-directives) directive names, and `data-` is accepted specifically for this reason.

Comment: @rism It's still the same even if you remove the `data-`.

Comment: @NewDev Yep you're right. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @wjohnsto sorry just miss type the n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a number of typos and errors:

- funtion instead of `function`
- agular instead of `angular`
- no jQuery included, but you call `$(function(){...})`

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oIDNJ2FNC8oC9oQ1CTvm?p=preview) with your code working.

Also, for future reference, if you remove .min from the angular source, it makes it easier to debug.

Comment: The problem is the `$` from `$(function(){});`, I thought Angular is extension of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Please add this directive to your body tag:
data-ng-app="zaskarCorp"

Also, you have some misspellings in your javascript code.

Comment: It's not working, sorry there is no misspellings I just miss type when putting it here.

Comment: Maybe you should include jQuery or remove "$(function..." completely? I removed that and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Without using jQLite your code will look like this:

```
var app = angular.module('zaskarCorp', []);

app.controller('kirito', function ($scope) {

$scope.items = [
    {
        "name": "dual sword",
        "quantity": 2
    }, 
    {
        "name": "gun",
        "quantity": 1
    }, 
    {
        "name": "laser sword",
        "quantity": 1
    }];
});
```

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-ng-app="zaskarCorp">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('zaskarCorp', []);

    app.controller('kirito', function($scope) {

      $scope.items = [{
        "name": "dual sword",
        "quantity": 2
      }, {
        "name": "gun",
        "quantity": 1
      }, {
        "name": "laser sword",
        "quantity": 1
      }];
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="kirito">
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in items">
      <span>{{item.name}}:{{item.quantity}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```